# how to Prevent alter a database

Tags: database, security

What is the best way to prevent changes to a database or verify the integrity of this, so that it can not be altered from an application created for this database.

assuming you have a username and password to access the database permits reading - writing.

#### requirements:

- The user has write permissions
- Do not depend on a particular system like (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server)

solution I'm looking for is not based on the user's permissions on the database

Comment: what brand/type of DB are you using?

Comment: If you're not looking for a solution based on database permissions (which, as everyone is pointing out, are the technical feature designed to do this), what are you looking for? You want to grant a user write permissions, but then prohibit them from writing to the db?

Comment: If you want to prevent *invalid* data from being put into the database, then you want a combination of application checks, and foreign key and check constraints. Unfortunately, support for check constraints varies widely across databases. You're going to have to be specific.

Comment: i'm no looking a specific database instructions. i'm looking for a technique, concept or strategy for apply

Comment: A technique, concept, or strategy to do *what*, exactly? And why can't you use permissions?

Comment: I want to ban all the changes are not made through a specific application. or at least identify them and then do something with them. something like signature all records

Comment: Then you need to give that specific application its own username/password, and have no other users with write permission. That's what permissions are for.

Comment: @derobert think about the following situation, someone took the database's user of the application, now updates any record or delete it, I want to verify the integrity of all records in a table

Comment: Maybe you're looking for database audit logging, then? That will let you record which rows are changed, when they changed, which database user (and probably remote IP address/port) changed them, etc. You can then use the logs to manually verify that the changes are legit. Details on audit logging are (unfortunately) database-specific.

Comment: maybe @derobert but there is a way to sign the records?

Comment: Maybe you could have your app store cryptographic signatures for the records, but if someone was able to obtain the app's user/password, why not its signing key as well?

Answer (score 0):

Most modern databases allow you to grant reading and writing permissions but while disallowing DDL commands like ALTER TABLE.

Do not give users that should not alter the DB structure permission to execute DDL.

If by "Alter" you mean change any data rows, rather than the database structure, you can grant the user only SELECT rights.

Comment: my problem is: the user has permissions for made changes i need a way to check integrity of information

Answer (score 0):

The user or account that your application uses must be granted permissions from the database server. Typically permissions include things like:

- Select
- Insert
- Update
- Delete
- Alter
- Drop

Only give the user account the permissions needed; in other words, don't grant `Alter` permission, and the application (or anyone using the same login) won't be able to alter tables.

Answer (score 0):

Two strategies: 1) if you are running SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, etc, you can configure permissions so users are reader/writer by default (which means no alter permissions).  2) you can periodically check to see if someone has changed the data structure or even set up a DB trigger to detect changes and record who/when, etc (depends on your DB platform)